# Why use AsyncStorage.setItem is no wroking?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I create a file `GetSetStorage` include `AsyncStorage`, when i try to use it i find its no working.

Here is my `GetSetStorage` file:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

class GetSetStorage {
  setStorageAsync(key, value) {
    console.log('start set storage');
    console.log(`key =>${key}`);
    console.log(`vaue =>${value}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Why is no working here ?');
      AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
        if (error) {
          console.log('===');
          console.log(`set${key}error${error}`);
          console.log('===');
          reject(`set${key}error${error}`);
        } else {
          console.log('===');
          console.log(`set${key}succeed`);
          console.log('===');
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  getStorageAsync(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(key, (error, result) => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('where is my error');
        if (error) {
          console.log('===');
          console.log(`load ${key} error ${error}`);
          console.log('===');
          reject(`load ${key} erro ${error}`);
        } else {
          console.log('===');
          console.log(`load ${key} succeed`);
          console.log('===');
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

export default new GetSetStorage();
```

I use it in my component like this:

```
import GetSetStorage from '../storage/GetSetStorage';

  componentWillMount() {
    GetSetStorage.setStorageAsync('testKey', 'test value');
  }
```

I see my console.log i find `setItem` is no working. Why ?
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//check it out !

```
state = {
        UserEmail: 'abcd@gmail.com'
      }

async setValue() {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.UserEmail));
 }



async getValue() {
  try {
       const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
         if (value !== null) {
            // We have data!!
            console.log(value);
         }
      } catch (error) {
          // Error retrieving data
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Asyncstorage also returns a promise so you can do something like

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.UserEmail))
  .then(() => console.log('saved email successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.error('something went wrong', err));
```

Similarly, to fetch the same key you can do something like:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('email')
.then(val => {
  if (val !== null) console.log(val); // You can do whatever you want with the email
})
.catch(err => console.error(err)) // if there was an error fetching data
```

Please note that if there is nothing in the async storage, it would return 'null' so in order to handle errors you need to put them in the if statement and not in catch